# Formula in Netsuite Saved Search

Tags: search, save, formula, netsuite

I have a problem here. In Column 1 I have count of All he transaction, In column 2 I have Count of transaction of specific status. In column 3 I want the percentage of above 2; like count of specific transaction/Count of total. Is it possible in Netsuite?

Comment: Do you need to use this in some SuiteScript, or is this specifically for use in the UI? If you do not need script access to this search, then I believe that you can accomplish this in a Report instead of a Saved Search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is an interesting feature that makes this possible. Formula fields that have aggregate functions work when the row has an aggregate on it. So for instance if you wanted to see a percentage of orders with status Billed on a Sales Order search you would enter a Formula (Percent) result with a formula like:

```
sum(case when {status} = 'Billed' then 1 else 0 end) / count({tranid})
```

and apply an aggregate to that column. The sample uses Maximum but Minimum and Average produce the same result.

[image: Saved Search Setup - All Sales Orders Since Nov 1]

[image: Saved Search Results Setup]

Answer (score 1):

I think that isn't possible by just saved search.

You will have to group on search result column `status`, so, all the count total will be based on statuses and you can't write aggregation based on other search results' columns.

you can further write a suitelet/portlet script to use the saved search result and calculate the stats before presenting on UI.